# tflite_runtime get Illegal instruction on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite

after installing tflite_runtime on raspberry pi using the following commands

```
echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/coral-edgetpu.list
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-tflite-runtime
```

and trying to import tflite .. I got "Illegal instruction"

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdf8u.jpg)

Comment: My guess would be that the package which is provided by that custom APT repo was not built for arm.

Comment: what raspberry model are you using ?

Comment: @rok its Raspberry Pi Zero W

Comment: @joelazar I've no idea how to get older version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prebuilt tflite_runtime package set from the above site does not cover armv6 architecture yet.

Alternatively, you can choose some other options.

(1) Install the TensorFlow pip package.

TensorFlow Lite features are a part of TensorFlow package and the prebuilt TensorFlow pip packages support armv6. See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

(2) Build your own tflite_runtime through Bazel or CMake.

If there is a need for installing the tflite_runtime only, it is possible to build the tflite_runtime by yourself. The following document describes the differences between Bazel and CMake and how to build the tflite_runtime through them.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm

Comment: thank you for your help, I'm going to check these solutions